# React Redux Array Filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

[image: Could some one tell how this image data iterate using array map and assign into the UL LI tag]
Could some one tell how this image data iterate using array map and assign into the UL LI tag
Assume this is the response generated from and I want to populate this data somewhere.

Comment: you need to return `return { ...state, addEmpoymentArr: filterArr }` this way it will return a new array for key `addEmpoymentArr`. The way you are writing means: `return { ...state, filterArr: filterArr }` it will add a new key value in the state.

Answer (score 0):

Specify key to access payload.

```
return { ...state, filterArr : filterArr }
```

Comment: amtuth, its not correct, there is no difference between what op wrote and the one you are suggesting :)

Comment: even i posted answer you too suggested same time bro

Comment: read my suggestion again, i suggested `return { ...state, addEmpoymentArr: filterArr }` :)

Comment: Thanks Mayank, Amryth.